# debug - IE Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

IE 7 started to throw following message

```
Line: 124
Character: 427
Code: 0
Error Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
URL: http://www.mysite.com
```

How should I find out more about which file is causing it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in the actual page

so you try to look for it in the source of the page (right click->view source)

or you can try to debug it using IE7 "Developer Toolbar" download it from the follwing:
[Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Comment: IE 7 doesn't have integrated developer tools.

Comment: @zeroflagL you're right totally forgot about it :)

developer tools are available on IE7 by download from here:
[Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) 
I'll edit my answer